# android: parse big portion of data

Tags: android, xml, parsing, base64, sax

I'm playing with android and trying to receive file (pdf book). To do this I wrote Servelt that encode the book into base64 string and put it in the XML document. That document contains name, author and IBSN fields also. I successfully receve it. In case of a small book I can even decode it and open. But if the size is more than 2mb I get OutOfMeoryError.
My parser code is:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if(builder==null) builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(new String(ch, start, length));
```

Then I do the following:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/book.pdf", false);
            byte[] toWrite = Base64.decode(builder.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            fos.write(toWrite);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
```

Does anybody know how can I parse it wothout error? I've tried to parse it in 
characters method (I mean using small buffer) but it fails... Illegal base 64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know how can I parse it wothout error?

You can't, most likely, as there is not enough RAM for you to work with.

Sensible programmers would not convert a large binary file into "base64 string and put it in the XML document". Sensible programmers would:

- put the metadata (name, author, ISBN) in property fields within the PDF, which is a fine solution for Java, but may be a problem for Android, as the libraries to get at those fields may or may not work (e.g., iText); or
- download the two files separately (one with the XML of metadata, which contains the URL to the PDF file); or
- package the PDF and the XML file into a single archive (e.g., ZIP) and download the archive

There may be other solutions than those three, but they should give you a starting point.